# How to add a .js file to the Svelte REPL?

Tags: svelte

In the [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/examples#hello-world) it is possible to add a new .svelte file but not a new .js file, but samples exist do have .js files:

https://svelte.dev/examples#derived-stores

Is it possible for end users to do the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add a new file (plus-sign), you need to just type `.js` at the end of file

Comment: Seems really obvious when you know about it :)